# Position of 也 in a sentence

Tags: grammar

In 你应该也吃不下番茄了吧？

Why 也 isn't right after 你？Cause generally 也 is the closest adverb to the subject like in 你们也都不 where the adverbs 都 and 不 are after 也 .

And as an adverb it would be place before 应该 which is a verb  , right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

你应该 = you should, and 也吃不下番茄了吧 is the statement about what you should

也 in the statement 也吃不下番茄了吧 modifies the verb 吃不下, in this case, **也吃不下** = **can't eat neither**

For example:

- 你应该**也**吃不下番茄 = you should be unable to eat tomato **neither**

If you put 也 directly after the subject, it can modify either the subject or the verb

For example:

- **你也** = **you too**
- [**你也**]应该吃不下番茄 = [**You too**] should be unable to eat tomato (imply there are other people who also can't eat tomato)
- **也吃不下** = **can't eat either**
- 你[**也应该吃不下番茄**] = you [**should be unable to eat tomato neither**] (imply there are other foods you can't eat)

Shorter example:

你应该**也有** - You should **have it too**

**你也**应该有 - **You too** should have it (imply everyone else already have it)

你**也应该有** - You **should have it too** (imply there are other things you already have)

Answer (score 2):

Both orders are possible, with a subtle nuance in meaning.

- 他饿了，你应该也饿了吧。
- 他饿了，你也应该饿了吧。

Both of the above sentences are all right.

- 你看起来很累，你应该也饿了吧。

In this case, only "应该也" feels natural and "也应该" feels awkward.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for a while, I found the two are essentially the same. For example:

既然已經吃撐了, 你**應該也**吃不下甜點了吧? = 既然已經吃撐了, 你**也應該**吃不下甜點了吧?

不能光吃肉, 你**應該也**吃一點青菜. = 不能光吃肉, 你**也應該**吃一點青菜.

如今兒女都長大了, 你**應該也**找個伴了. = 如今兒女都長大了, 你**也應該**找個伴了.